# Debugging Karma, mocha & webpack inside IntelliJ

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, karma-runner, karma-mocha, karma-webpack

I am failing to debug mocha unit tests, using karma and webpack.
I have the Karma plugin installed, and the chrome extension. But when I'm debugging the IDE would just ignore any breakpoints.

Example of a unit test:

```
var assert = require('chai').assert;

describe('Test', function () {
    it('always true', function () {
        assert.equal(1 === 1, true);
    });
});
```

Comment: did you ever managet to get that working?